# Why my python still shows 2.7.3 after installing 2.7.6

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I initially had `python 2.7.3` i downloaded from the sourcee and did `make install`

and after downloading i run `python`

but again my system is showing `2.7.3`

I didn't get any error while installing

Comment: Did your system have 2 versions of Python ? What is the output of `which python` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you're executing the newly installed version?  Try saying `readlink -f $(which python)`

Comment: @devnull the output is /usr/bin/python2.7

Comment: Maybe your `python2.7.3` is in `/usr/bin/`, `python2.7.6` is in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin/` is prior in `$PATH`. Use `which python` to find what python interpreter you are using and `-V` to print the version.

Comment: Supply the absolute path to the version you installed.

Comment: may be `/usr/bin/python2.7` links to `/usr/bin/python2.7.3`, check the link or something similar. Do that: `readlink /usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: @devnull the new version is here /usr/local/bin/python, how can i link usr/bin/python to this

Comment: The way to do this in Ubuntu is using a tool called pyenv. See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21303025/1839209) below.

Comment: If you want to make the new version the default you could say `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are on Ubuntu, I recommend following the steps outlined [here](http://heliumhq.com/docs/installing_python_2.7.5_on_ubuntu) to install a new Python version. The steps there are for Python 2.7.5 but should be equally applicable to Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Is the Pyenv same as virtualenc because i am using virtualenv for Django

Comment: No, virtualenv is for managing different versions of libraries. Pyenv is for managing different versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The version you installed is probably in /usr/local/bin/python . Try calling it with the complete path. You may want to change your path settings or remove the previously installed version using your package manager if it was installed by the system.

Comment: u r right the new version is `/usr/local/bin/python`